# Quantum Circuit To Compute Any Inner Product

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm currently reading the paper [Classification with Quantum Neural Networks on Near Term Processors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.06002.pdf)

It shows a method to determine the following quantity:

[image]

Where U is a unitary operator acting on $|z,1\rangle$. The paper states the following:
[image]
[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to calculate any general inner product like $\langle z_2, 1|U|z, 1\rangle$ or just $\langle a | b \rangle $ in general? How could I modify the circuit to do so? (or is there a different methodology to calculate the inner product with different vectors?)

Comment: The inner product between two states can be computed using the [SWAP test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test). Is that what you're looking for?
Also, some interesting details regarding efficient implementation on NISQ devices can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04114).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use the SWAP test to determine the inner product of 2 states $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$. The circuit is shown below [image: SWAP Test Circuit]

The state of the system at the beginning of the protocol is $|0\rangle \otimes |\phi \rangle \otimes |\psi \rangle$. After the Hadamard gate, the state of the system is $|+\rangle \otimes |\phi \rangle \otimes |\psi \rangle$.

The controlled SWAP gate transforms the state into $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}|0\rangle \otimes |\phi \rangle \otimes |\psi \rangle + |1\rangle \otimes |\psi \rangle \otimes |\phi \rangle$.

The second Hadamard gate results in
$$\frac {1}{2}(|0\rangle|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle +|1\rangle|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle +|0\rangle|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle -|1\rangle|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle ) \\
=\frac {1}{2}|0\rangle (|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle +|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle)+ \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle(|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle -|\psi\rangle|\phi \rangle)$$

The Measurement gate on the first qubit ensures that it's 0 with a probability of
$P(\text{First qubit}=0)=\frac {1}{2}\Big(\langle\phi|\langle\psi| + \langle\psi|\langle\phi|\Big ) \frac {1}{2}\Big (|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle + |\psi\rangle |\phi\rangle \Big )=\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{2}|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^{2}$ when measured.

The downside of this test is that the qubits cannot be recovered to the same state as before. Hence $|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle|$ must be prepared multiple times independently in order to get a good probability estimate and hence the value of inner product.